# What does the error "invalid types ... for array subscript" mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, g++

I can see several references to this error on SO, and though the answers all seem to solve the original compile error, none of them explain what the error is really saying.

I am compiling my cpp file with: `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 myfile.cpp`, and get the error below:

```
myfile.cpp: In function ‘void GenerateMatrix(uint8_t**, uint8_t)’:
myfile.cpp:32:39: error: invalid types ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}[uint8_t {aka unsigned char}]’ for array subscript
    std::cout << ", " << (*matrix)[i][j];
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

//// populates an n x n matrix.
//// @return the matrix 
void GenerateMatrix(uint8_t** matrix, uint8_t n)
{

    *matrix = (uint8_t*)malloc(n * n);

    uint8_t* pc = *matrix;
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(uint8_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            *pc++ = i+j;
        }
    }

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(uint8_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            std::cout << ", " << (*matrix)[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main()
{
    uint8_t* matrix = nullptr;
    uint8_t n = 10;
    GenerateMatrix(&matrix, n);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried changing `i` and `j` in the second for loop to be `int`. That gave me a similar error, but this time the complaint was about `invalid types ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}[int]’`, and I am still none the wiser.

Can anyone help me understand this error?

Comment: This is C++, you shouldn't be using malloc/free, but instead `new uint8_t[n*n]` and `delete[] matrix` (well, you didn't free anyway, so you actually produced a memory leak...). *Exception*: You are writing code that explicitly shall be usable from C as well (so if the array is returned by some `extern "C"` function, directly or indirectly).

Comment: you declared a linear array whose linear elements are N*N in number, you didn't declare a double dimensional array.

Comment: @Aconcagua. yes 100% agree. however, even if I do `new uint8_t[n][n]`. I still get the same compile error.

Comment: @BithikaMookherjee Ah, should have marked my comment as *'off-topic'*...

Comment: @Aconcagua haha ok point taken :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void generateMatrix(uint8_t** matrix, uint8_t n)
//                         ^^
{
    (*matrix) // type is uint8_t*
    [i]       // type is uint8_t
    [j];      // ???
}
```

What you actually do is equivalent to:

```
uint8_t n = 10;
n[12] = 7;   // no index ('subscript'!) applicable to raw unsigned char
             // or with compiler words, the unsigned char is an invalid
             // type for this operation to be applied on...
```

The same message might appear as well in the other direction:

```
class C { }; // note that there's no cast operator to some integral type provided!

int array[7];
C c;
array[c]; // just that this time it's the other operand that has invalid type...
```